# Embedded Games for my https Sites

Tags: http, https, game-engine

How can i add  Embedded  Games to  my **https** Sites?

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.freeonlinegames.com/embed/124339' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.freeonlinegames.com/static/ima-vast-preroll.swf': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

I try to remove http from the URL but nothing.
Please may be somebody could help me?